# Average of a list in Python

Tags: python, csv, average

I have a file "list1" that contain Name, Surname, Note1, Note2, like this:

```
DUPOND, John, 12, 10
JAMES, Fil, 8, 10
KYLE, Gregor, 17, 7
```

I want to write a Python script to display in another file called "list2", the content of "list1"
but sorted and with the average of the 2 notes in the format : Surname, Name, Note1, Note2, Average
like this:

```
John, DUPOND, 12, 14, 13
JAMES, Fil, , 8, 10, 9
KYLE, Gregor, 17, 7, 12
```

Do you have advice to give ?

I have tested this code it's only display the content of my file in square bracket, how can i make the average of the 2 value and put it in another file?

```
import sys
import csv

with open(sys.argv[1], newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
     statistics.mean(xs)
        print(row)
```

Comment: Where do you define `xs`?

Comment: [How to ask a homework question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: You forgot to import `statistics`.

Comment: Your inputs and outputs don't agree. Please fix the names to match the description, or fix the description. Make the input values match the output (e.g. `12, 10` in one should not be `12, 14` in the other).

Comment: Do you know what these square brackets mean? You see a representation of a list. The elements of the list can be accessed via their index. If you do not know how this works, please read about [Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) in the tutorial.

Comment: To put the results in another file, open the output file and use `csv.writer()`. Use `row.append()` to add the average to the end of the row before calling `writer.writerow(row)`

Comment: You have an extra `,` in the second line of the output file.

Comment: use the `skipinitialspace=True` option to `csv.reader()` to ignore the spaces after the `,`.

Comment: Are there spaces in the text file or was that added here in the example? Normally a CSV file wouldn't have extra spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps involved here are:

1. Read a row, unpack the name components and the values separately
2. Compute the mean of the values (which will require converting them to `int`; `csv` reads them as `str`)
3. Write out the name components in reverse order, the values, and the mean

```
import sys
import csv
import statistics

with open(sys.argv[1], newline='') as inf, open(sys.argv[2], 'w', newline='') as outf:
    writer = csv.writer(outf)
    for name, surname, *values in csv.reader(inf):  # Read name first, surname second, then collect values
        writer.writerow([surname, name, *values, statistics.mean(map(int, values))])  # Write surname first, then name, then values, then average
```

This works even if the number of values is something other than two, since the unpacking handles all extra values by collecting them into the `values` `list`, however many there may be.